# How to write xaml code to xaml.cs, Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.1, 0.5, AutoSize, AutoSize"
```

How to write the property above programmatically in xaml.cs?

I tried

```
ContactUsButton.Layout(
    new Rectangle(1.12, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
```

But no luck, it seems it is not working. I could not find any member `AbsoluteLayout` or `AbsoluteLayoutBounds` of class.

### Edit (Answer):

I have figured it out:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(
    ContactUsButton,
    new Rectangle(1.12, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
```

For use of anyone,

BR,

Comment: You should post the answer as an answer below, and then accept it. That's the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as below;

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(
ContactUsButton,
new Rectangle(1.12, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
```